How to merge 2 pandas dataframes based on criteria
I’m having some issues joining 2 dataframes using pandas.merge(), based on certain conditions. I would appreciate some advice
In the example below, I wish to join the 2 dataframes on customerId. However, I’m interested in only the EARLIEST record in loans_df which matches the condition:

Customers.EndDate < Loans.Date
Loans.amount > 100

This means it’s a one-to-one join (or one to zero if no loans exists for a customer). Note: I’m assuming the date convention is yyyymmdd.
import pandas as pd 

Customer_df = pd.DataFrame({ 'CustomerId': [1,2,3], 'End date ': [‘20240101’, ‘20220101’, ‘20250101’] }) 
Loans_df = pd.DataFrame({ 'LoanId': [1,2,3], 'CustomerId': [1,2,2], ‘Date’: [‘20240112’, ‘20230101’, ‘20240101’], 'Amount': [1000,2000,4000]})


Tried pandas.merge() without success

It looks like a merge_asof after pre-filtering Loans_df to only keep the values above 100:
# prerequisite: ensure correct datetime
# Customer_df['End date'] = pd.to_datetime(Customer_df['End date'], format='%Y%m%d')
# Loans_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(Loans_df['Date'], format='%Y%m%d')

out = pd.merge_asof(Customer_df.sort_values(by='End date'),
                    Loans_df.query('Amount > 100').sort_values(by='Date'),
                    left_on='End date', right_on='Date', by='CustomerId',
                    direction='forward'
                   )

Output:
   CustomerId   End date  LoanId       Date  Amount
0           2 2022-01-01     2.0 2023-01-01  2000.0
1           1 2024-01-01     1.0 2024-01-12  1000.0
2           3 2025-01-01     NaN        NaT     NaN

If you only want the matches, add a dropna:
out = (pd.merge_asof(Customer_df.sort_values(by='End date'),
                     Loans_df.query('Amount > 100').sort_values(by='Date'),
                     left_on='End date', right_on='Date', by='CustomerId',
                     direction='forward')
         .dropna(subset=['Date'])
      )

Output:
   CustomerId   End date  LoanId       Date  Amount
0           2 2022-01-01     2.0 2023-01-01  2000.0
1           1 2024-01-01     1.0 2024-01-12  1000.0

